# cin.getline in while loop

Tags: c++, getline

I am doing homework for school, and basically when you enter `"VIP"`, `vip++` should be done. It won't even build when I put `cin.getline` in while loop. `getline` usually works in other codes but I don't understand it this time. Can someone help me?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
  int istok = 0, zapad = 0, loza = 0, vip = 0, mladi = 0;

  cout << "Unesite I za istok, Z za zapad, L za lozu, VIP za VIP (rofl), M za "
          "djecu i mlade."
       << endl;

  char unos5;

  while (unos5 != 'K') {
    cin.getline(unos5, 5);

    if (unos5 == 'I') {
      istok++;
    }

    else if (unos5 == 'Z') {
      zapad++;
    }

    else if (unos5 == 'L') {
      loza++;
    }

    else if (unos5 == 'VIP') {
      vip++;
    }

    else if (unos5 == 'M') {
      mladi++;
    }

    /*else if(unos5 != 'I' || 'Z' || 'L' || 'VIP' || 'M'){
            cout<<"Unjeli ste krivo! Pokusajte ponovno."<<endl;
            cin>>unos5;
    }*/

    else if (unos5 == 'K') {
      break;
    }
  }

  cout << "Ukupna zarada od prodanih ulaznica je "
       << istok * 60 + zapad * 80 + loza * 100 + vip * 500 + mladi * 20
       << " kn." << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The argument to `getlne` needs to be an array of `char`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline.

Comment: This code can't possibly compile. `cin.getline(unos5, 5);` doesn't make sense with `unos5` of type `char`. The code you show can't be the code you are actually running. Show a [mcve].

Comment: What do you expect `'VIP'` to be?

Comment: You should convert the text to all upper case (std::toupper) before comparing.

Comment: No, don't use `std::toupper`, because it's not compatible with UTF-8, which you're using. Right? Right...?

Comment: Remember, a `char` type holds **one** character.  `std::string` holds many characters.  The text `VIP` is 3 letters, not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `cout`, `cin` and `endl` are in the `std` namespace, so you need to either prepend `std::` to them of add lines like `using std::cout;` after the `#include`s.

Regarding your code, the `getline` member of `istream` (the type of `cin`) requires a char array, but you only define a char. I suggest not to use char arrays but use the free function `getline` that gets a stream to read from as a parameter and that stores the result in a `std::string` which allows safer and easier handling. As you did not use `<cstring>` and `getline` is in `<string>` I changed that `#include`.

Also your 'VIP' cannot do something useful. These are three characters in one, that cannot work. You need a string for it (double quotes, not single quotes).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{

    int istok = 0, zapad = 0, loza = 0, vip = 0, mladi = 0;

    cout << "Unesite I za istok, Z za zapad, L za lozu, VIP za VIP (rofl), M za djecu i mlade." << endl;

    std::string unos5;

    while (unos5 != "K") {
        std::getline(std::cin, unos5);

        if (unos5 == "I") {
            istok++;
        }

        else if (unos5 == "Z") {
            zapad++;
        }

        else if (unos5 == "L") {
            loza++;
        }

        else if (unos5 == "VIP") {
            vip++;
        }

        else if (unos5 == "M") {
            mladi++;
        }

        /*else if(unos5 != 'I' || 'Z' || 'L' || 'VIP' || 'M'){
                cout<<"Unjeli ste krivo! Pokusajte ponovno."<<endl;
                cin>>unos5;
        }*/

        else if (unos5 == "K") {
            break;
        }


    }

    cout << "Ukupna zarada od prodanih ulaznica je " << istok * 60 + zapad * 80 + loza * 100 + vip * 500 + mladi * 20 << " kn." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Please also note that writing `endl` has the effect of writing '\n' and then calling `flush()` on the output stream. If you don't need the `flush()`, then you should only write '\n'.

Comment: @RSahu Once again you raise a good point. Changed the answer... again :).